# PouchDb data not updating on Get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, pouchdb

Hi I have tried to fetching the data from pouch db local database.

Here my code.

```
function test(){

var jsondata;

var deviceId = localStorage.getItem("deviceId");    

localDB.get(deviceId).then(function(doc){                 

  jsondata = doc.data;

});
return jsondata}

test();
```

Here I can get the console data inside get function but from the last line I was getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part inside the function is executed after the promise is resolved.

The `console.log` at the end is executed immediately after the `localDB.get` statement. At this point, the promise hasn't been resolved, the callback hasn't been executed and hence the value of `jsondata` hasn't been set - leaving `undefined` as the value of `jsondata`

**Edit 1:**

```
var jsondata;

var deviceId = localStorage.getItem("deviceId");    

localDB.get(deviceId).then(function(doc){                 

  jsondata = doc.data;
  console.log(jsondata)

  // whatever you want to do with `jsondata`,
  // do it here
});

// not here
```

**Edit 2:**

If this code is to be placed in a function, you should return the promise itself. So your code becomes something like:

```
function getDoc(){

    var deviceId = localStorage.getItem("deviceId");    

    return localDB.get(deviceId);
}
```

Now resolve this promise using `.then()` in that place in your code where you need to use `jsondata`

```
.
.
getDoc().then(function(doc){
    // your code that needs to use the document
});
.
.
```

Comment: Whatever you want to do with the retrieved document, you should do it in within the callback.

Comment: Sorry Kul am new to here. Can you please send me th code snippet for this

Comment: That part I can understand, How could I return the value If I use in function. (I have edited my question)

Comment: Are you saying that this code is in a function that needs to return the resolved value?

Comment: Yes, Exactly   Kul. Please help me on this